# How would I reduce an element-wise operation (such as eq or gt) to a number?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Hopefully, I am asking the right thing and not chasing wild ducks here.

Let's assume I have this dataframe:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(
  {'measurement1': np.random.rand(31), 'measurement2': np.random.rand(31)}, 
  index=pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-01-31')
)
```

Is there any way to get the count of all values greater than 0.15, for example, from the result of gt(), or am I looking at this the wrong way?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure.  Add `sum` go get it columnwise, sum(axis=1) rowwise, sum twice to get total for the entire dataframe/ or use np.sum.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(1)
df = pd.DataFrame(
  {'measurement1': np.random.rand(31), 'measurement2': np.random.rand(31)}, 
  index=pd.date_range(start='2020-01-01', end='2020-01-31')
)

df.gt(.15).sum()
```

Output:

```
measurement1    23
measurement2    24
dtype: int64
```

Row-wise:

```
df.gt(.15).sum(axis=1)
```

Output:

```
2020-01-01    2
2020-01-02    2
2020-01-03    1
2020-01-04    2
2020-01-05    1
2020-01-06    1
2020-01-07    2
2020-01-08    1
2020-01-09    2
2020-01-10    2
2020-01-11    2
2020-01-12    2
2020-01-13    2
2020-01-14    1
2020-01-15    1
2020-01-16    2
2020-01-17    2
2020-01-18    2
2020-01-19    0
2020-01-20    1
2020-01-21    2
2020-01-22    2
2020-01-23    2
2020-01-24    2
2020-01-25    1
2020-01-26    2
2020-01-27    0
2020-01-28    1
2020-01-29    2
2020-01-30    1
2020-01-31    1
Freq: D, dtype: int64
```

Entire dataframe:

```
df.gt(.15).sum().sum()
```

or

```
np.sum(df.gt(.15).to_numpy())
```

Output:

```
47
```